# Wordpress and Widget using TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I have written a Text/HTML widget that uses TinyMCE to allow some basic formatting.  However, when I save the changes, the data in the textarea is not getting posted.  If I use just a simple textarea without TinyMCE then I can save the data properly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue recently as well. Just solved it, actually. :)

If you write a PHP function to include your tinyMCE code and run the Javascript init, you can include that in admin_head

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-widgets.php', 'NAME OF YOUR INIT FUNCTION HERE' );
```

Currently I've also go the following in my init function. although I'm not certain it's needed in this context:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'editor' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'editor_functions' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags' );
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it post at all? Do a

```
<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>
```

on the page its posting to, and see if value is is being passed. 99% of the time its a typing error, perhaps the textarea name is wrong.